# css property doesn't load

Tags: css, angularjs, document-ready

I need to set the background property of a label for the css property in a angular controller.js file. 
I am using jquery to update the background. 
Below is my code: Here if $scope.isInside is true I need one color and if false I need another. This .norow is applied to a DIV in HTML.
The issue is it doesn't work consistently. Sometime the backgound color gets set and sometimes it doesn't.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    if ($scope.isinside){
        $(".norow label").css("background-color","#ffffdd");
    }
    else{
        $(".norow label").css("background-color","#ffffff");
    }
});
```

Comment: A littlle off-topic, but why use `angular.element(document)` when you could use the jQuery `$(document)` (you use jQuery later)?

Comment: Could it be that `$scope.isinside` should be `$scope.isInside` (with camel-case like you stated in your question)? And when it sets the `background-color` to `#ffffff` (white) could you be mistaking that for not being set?

Comment: <div ng-class="norow" style="display:inline;"><label for="sind">Select one industry</label></h3></div> is my div

Comment: @Jonathan, if I use JQUERY onready. its not reading my class norow. hence I have to use angualr way. And the property here is any typo. I am using correct one. "isinside"

Comment: Can you try `class="norow"` instead of `ng-class="norow"`? I think Angular's `ng-class` expects an expression and may be treating it as a variable

Comment: I tried that one too. I doesn't behave consistently. Just to add, norow is already defined in css. And I am just adding background color here in controller

Comment: can you post more of your code? i think you might need $scope.$apply()

Comment: In the controller.    angular.element(document).ready(function () {  
  if ($scope.isinside){
   $(".norow label").css("background-color","#ffffdd");
  }
  else{
   $(".norow label").css("background-color","#ffffff");
  }


 });           In HTML: <div ng-class="norow" style="display:inline;"><label for="sind">Select one industry</label></h3></div>

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-style:

```
<label ng-style="{'background-color': isinside ? '#ffffdd': '#ffffff'}" > something </label>
```

You can also use ng-class:

```
<label ng-class="{'grey-bg': isinside, 'white-bg': !isinside}"> something </label>
```